# javascript returning NaN when sum

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to do a addition sum with javascript to work out the user total cost when their goods and shipping are added together, however all I get returned is NaN why is? Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zXF5k/) of my code

#### Code ported from fiddle:

```
 $("#country").change(function() {
    var shipping_cost = parseFloat($("#shipping").text().replace(pattern, ''));
    var total      = parseFloat($("#goods").text().replace(pattern, ''));
    var pattern = /[^0-9.-]+/g;
    var result = total + shipping_cost;
    console.log(result);

       if($(this).val() == "17") {
           $("#shipping").text("£0.00");
           $("#full_price").text("£"+result);
       } else {
           $("#shipping").text("£5.00");
           $("#full_price").text("£"+result);
       }
 });​
```

#### Markup:

```
<select id="country">
    <option value=17>Option 1</option>
    <option value=18>Option 2</option>
    <option value=19>Option 3</option>
</select>

<p id=goods>£5.00</p>

<p id=shipping>£0.00<p>
```

Comment: _If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseFloat returns NaN._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `var pattern = /[^0-9.-]+/g;` up, and everything should work fine:

```
var pattern = /[^0-9.-]+/g;
var shipping_cost = parseFloat($("#shipping").text().replace(pattern, ''));
var total      = parseFloat($("#goods").text().replace(pattern, ''));
```

Answer (score 7):

Your pattern declaration should come before your parse, like so:

```
var pattern = /[^0-9.-]+/g;
var shipping_cost = parseFloat($("#shipping").text().replace(pattern, ''));
var total      = parseFloat($("#goods").text().replace(pattern, ''));
```